# Roman numeral analysis of exam practice exercise: "Polish Song" by Hiller

Tags: harmony, analysis, roman-numerals, exam-grades

The piece in question is 'Polish Song' by Hiller. I have labelled the bars from 1 to 11.

The piece is in A minor, and we seem to have A minor leading to V7 in the opening measures (I'm putting the C in the melody down as V13).

- **Bar 3**: We have a G natural in the bass. I was tempted to sharp it, but there doesn't seem to be space for the A natural resolution at the beginning of the next bar, so perhaps this is minor chord v?
- **Bars 5/6**: We have C E G, with B in the bass, which could imply a major chord III? (not augmented.) I flirted with the idea of this being V7 (with an added 13), but the melody notes in the next bar seem to suggest this does not resolve to the i chord. Any ideas as to what is going on here harmonically speaking?
- **Bar 9**: seems to be V7 but in second inversion. If I put a G sharp underneath the B (to change it to first inversion) the texture becomes cluttered. As far as I know, this actually shouldn't be a legitimate place for a second inversion chord, as it is on the strongest beat of the bar and is obviously not part of a cadencial 6 4. So what is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: ABRSM grade 8 Theory Workbook

Comment: I think bar 4 is `III` in root position, not `i` in first inversion.  Does that change your thinking at all?

Comment: Hello again! thanks for responding. Ah yes, I see. In which case it could go: bar 4- III, bar 5- III7, bar 6- minor v (or III7 again),  bar 7- ii7, bar 8-  Major V, bar 9- V7? Interested to know your opinion on that second inversion V7 in bar 9.

Comment: @EdB123 Unfortunately I am less familiar with this period (and particularly the structure of folk melodies doesn't always fit precisely with common-practice harmony).  But 9 does seem likely to be `V7` without a third.  Again, it would be easier to be certain of that if one could see the rest of the piece (or at least as far as the first measure without an E in the bass). I'm on the fence about m5 because I don't see anything suggesting whether the B is a chord tone (Cmaj7) or perhaps there's a quick `V/III-III` progression there.  Are there clues later in the piece?

Comment: Also I hope you recognized that the analysis of the last beat of m3 has to change if m4 is `III`.

Comment: hi phoog-

Is there a way I can send you a picture of the whole piece?

Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**m. 3**

The G natural in the bass on beat 3 lets us know this is V/III.

**mm. 5-6**

Bar 5, beat 1 is V<sup>6</sup>/III, moving to III for beats 2 and 3. Bar 6 is most likely a C major echo of bars 1 and 2, so III on beats 1 and 2, followed by V#/i on beat 3.

**m. 9**

This is V7 in root position; however, the root happens to be delayed until the end of the measure.

Comment: Just given it a proper look. I'm sure you are correct, but was just going to ask your reasoning behind interpreting the end of bar 3 as V/III and not a major III back to chord i (although im aware thats not a very common progression).  Would you say that this is essentially a key change to the relative major as of bar 3?i suppose bar 5 is a further clue? Or are we still in A minor? Also, are you calling it Vsharp/i to underline the point the G is now sharpened for this chord? Thanks very much for your help (yet again!)

Comment: Bar 4 is a cadence in the relative major; very common in minor keys. And yes, the sharp sign is to clarify that the V chord includes G#.

Comment: Hi Aaron, just working through this piece again. Just wondering about your choice of major V of i on beat 3 of bar 6. If this was a 'C major echo' of bars 1 and 2, wouldn't the harmony be III for the first 2 beats, but V of III for the last beat, as opposed to V of i? I know the next chord isnt III, but it isn't minor i either- so just wondering how you arrived at this? thanks!

Comment: @EdB123 Bar 7 is clearly back in A minor, so the "echo" ends in favor of a transition via V/i.

Comment: Hi Aaron- what chord/ chords would you say bar 7 is? I decided against A minor down to the leap between the B and the D.